# QuerySelectorAll will not work as expected on an img alt

Tags: javascript

Here is the line of code I am trying to target: `<img class="pi" src="/graphics/ni/ni90.jpg" alt="Awaiting image">`

I'm trying to select all of the images that have the attribute `alt="Awaiting image"`

If I try `document.querySelectorAll("img.pi");`

I will get all of the images that have the class `pi`

If I try `document.querySelectorAll("img.pi[alt="Awaiting image"]");`

I will get the error:`Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

What is it that I am missing here?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll("img.pi[alt="Awaiting image"]");` -> `document.querySelectorAll('img.pi[alt="Awaiting image"]');` or `document.querySelectorAll("img.pi[alt='Awaiting image']");`

Comment: You need to escape the quotes:`document.querySelectorAll("img.pi[alt=\"Awaiting image\"]");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"` used to delimit the value in the attribute selector are clashing with the `"` used to delimit the JS string literal.

```
 document.querySelectorAll("img.pi[alt="Awaiting image"]");
                           ^           ^^
                           |           |Error
                           |           End of string
                           Start of string
```

Use a different kind of quote.

```
 document.querySelectorAll('img.pi[alt="Awaiting image"]');
```